# Unable to build SQL Server Project V12 because of AT TIME ZONE

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server Project in Visual Studio 2015 that targets SQL Azure V12 that does not build.  We have several stored procedures that use "AT TIME ZONE" which causes syntax errors when I try to build the project.

I can manually deploy these stored procedures to our SQL Azure V12 databases and they work as expected.  So, from a functional standpoint we are good to go, I just cannot deploy these stored procedures using a database project.

This question has already been asked but was never answered so I figured I would repost the question.

It is very easy to produce just add the line of code below (from Microsoft's site) to any stored procedure in a database project targeting V12 and it will fail the build.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '03/29/2015 01:01:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time';
```

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Loading Update 3 for Visual Studio 2015 fixed the problem.